# Error coming as java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.Project in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

While Running i am getting an Error  as java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.Project while running spring boot application in Spring toll Suite(Version: 3.9.5.RELEASE) using Spring boot App

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.Project
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.getProject(AntCompiler.java:72) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:595) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
```

i run the project in STS as by right click on Project-->Run AS -->Spring Boot App.

i tried to clean and update the maven,clean and rebuild the project.. still getting the same error.. Kindly help me what else can we do to remove this exception.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the following dependecy in you pom file and then execute `mvn package`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: already there is a inbuilt  web starter dependency and I added apache-tomcat-embed dependency, so adding separate dependency which you provided in your answer section as org.apache.ant will not affect the other dependency in project ??  And thanks for your solution, will try this for sure now and get back to u ASAP

Comment: Thanks a lot sir..Its working smoothly after adding ant dependency.

Comment: @user2715085 i'm glad that it helped